# record sound from speakers or stereo mix

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've searched some examples and found this:

```
var
  op: TMCI_Open_Parms;
  rp: TMCI_Record_Parms;
  sp: TMCI_SaveParms;
begin

  // Open
  op.lpstrDeviceType := 'waveaudio';
  op.lpstrElementName := '';
  if mciSendCommand(0, MCI_OPEN, MCI_OPEN_ELEMENT or MCI_OPEN_TYPE, cardinal(@op)) <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('MCI error');

  try

    // Record
    rp.dwFrom := 0;
    rp.dwTo := 10000;
    rp.dwCallback := 0;
    if mciSendCommand(op.wDeviceID, MCI_RECORD, MCI_TO or MCI_WAIT, cardinal(@rp)) <> 0 then
      raise Exception.Create('MCI error. No microphone connected to the computer?');

    // Save
    sp.lpfilename := PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test.wav');
    if mciSendCommand(op.wDeviceID, MCI_SAVE, MCI_SAVE_FILE or MCI_WAIT, cardinal(@sp)) <> 0 then
      raise Exception.Create('MCI error');

  finally
    mciSendCommand(op.wDeviceID, MCI_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  end;
```

it records only microphone, can I record speakers and microphone simultaniously? or separately?

Comment: What do you mean by "record the speakers"?  That is of course, a fundamental absurdity, unless you mean "I want to place a microphone beside my speakers and record the room around the speakers".  Maybe you mean you want to hijack the audio output stream within the Windows device driver layer before it reaches the audio card, after which point, of course, the signal is an output, not an input?

Comment: I want to record sound from microphone and from pc (input & output) e.g: I play music on youtube + talking with microphone, making comments ..

Comment: @WarrenP:  Actually. I'm not sure the OP's reference to "record the speakers" is so absurd.  On this PC, the *input* device for the Audacity recorder app is listed as "Speakers (Conexant 20585 Smart Audio HD)".

Comment: @MartynA, in this case microphone should be used as playback device.

Comment: @FreeConsulting but screen recorders record PC sounds too

Comment: @FreeConsulting:  Not arging but: on my Thinkpad T410 (+Win7 and Win10 64-bit) , Audacity works fine recording from the Conexant speaker devive and with the microphone device disabled.

Comment: Teamviewer transferes computer sounds to the client too

Comment: In my opinion "record the audio output of a particular program, or all programs" would be a better way of saying what the OP said. however given that others who google might think differently, this question has merit. Recording this way would work even if you had no speakers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to do this largely depends on which Windows version are you using.

If you are still using Windows XP you might have "Software mix" or "Stereo out" recoding channels available.

But if you are using Windows Vista or newer these channels are no longer available. Well not without the use of some unofficial sound card drivers.

The main reason for this is that ability to record entire sound card output was invalidating any digital copyright protection for audio files.

So in order to achieve what you need you will have to find some custom sound library which would be able to directly play the music from Youtube mix your microphone with hat and output (record) that into some file.

I think you might be able to achieve this with Bass sound library (http://www.un4seen.com/) but I'm not sure.

Another option would be to directly connect `Wave Out` line into `Line in` port using cable and then record contents from `Line in` instead from microphone. Also make sure to allow your microphone voice to be played over speakers (disabled by default on most sound cards for avoiding possible sound echo).

**EDIT**: After taking a look at program named Audacity I found out that recording of your computers sound output only works if you chose WASAPI as sound interface.

Looking further about the WASAPI it seems this is new audio interface that has been introduced with Windows Vista. Now I must admit that I haven't known about this before.

So it seems that answer would lie in using WASAPI instead of old MME audio interface.

Quick search on Google does indicate that some people already managed to use WASAPI from Delphi.

Now since I don't have any experience with this new sound API I'm afraid that I can't be of more help to you than recommending you to learn about WASAPI and find some examples for it.

**EDIT2:** Managed to find a small example of using WASAPI interface in Delphi for Loopback recording. You can get it here:

http://4coder.org/delphi-source-code/547/

Also found a thread on DelphiPraxis about someone making a specially purposed unit for loopback recording with WASAPI in Delphi but since I'm not a member of DelphiPraxis I can't download it and test it.

http://www.delphipraxis.net/183977-wasapi-loopback-audio-capturing.html

Comment: Can I do without + .dlls in my program?

Comment: Hi, SW.  I'm not arguing, just curious:  How come, then, that even in Windows7, Audacity manages to record from the "speakers" device (see my comment to WarrenP)?

Comment: Somehow some screen recorders record computer sounds too (what comes out of speakers) how do they do it..

Comment: I have edited my answer with some more information. I'm sorry if I can't be of more help in this. It has been some time since I was playing with and idea for some sound related project of mine.

Comment: yes, I've found WASAPI too but some manages to record loopback from stereomix

Comment: @SilverWarior:  I think you're right about WASAPI.  When I first upgraded to Win7, the then-current Audacity version could not record from the Speakers device, and there was a note in the Audacity help about this and recommending the use of a physical cable to LineIn; I never used a cable, but had to record from the Headphones output with phyical headphones muted or unplugged.  Iirc, when Audacity was updated subsequently to support WASAPI, it became possible (for me) to record from the Speakers device without a cable.

Comment: I managed to find a Delphi example which supports Loopback recording so you can record what is being played on your speakers. And yes it does use WASAPI. Updating my answer with a link to the example.

Comment: I've found delphipraxis too. this is it. 4coder src is more simpler than delphipraxis.

Comment: I'm glad I could have been of help